# How does Rest assured 3.0.6 pretty print display two items response whereas actual response contains one item?

Tags: java, rest, api, rest-assured

How does Rest assured 3.0.6 pretty print display two items response whereas actual response contains one item? In postman and asString method it is showing one item only.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the System.out.println. Putting it there is what's causing it to print twice.  All you need is:

```
res.body().prettyPrint();
```

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to do the same with the request.
I am using GraphQL and it would be nice to see the query logged "beautified" especially when using variable. If the query is long that might help quite a lot